# Set HTML5 Cache Manifest from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-appcache

I'm generating the cache manifest serverside, and I need to include bits of information through querystrings.

My problem is, that the information I need to include is only obtainable by using Javascript. So the page needs to load, then some javascript processing, and finally setting a manifest url (and update the cache).

So in essence:

`$("html").attr("manifest", "/cache.manifest?varfromjs= + somevar);`

This does nothing though, and I've tried calling `window.applicationCache.update()`, but I get an error stating "INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11".

This is on latest stable Google Chrome. It seems to work in Firefox though.

This is my first time using HTML5 appcache, so I may have missed something. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think cache manifest attribute can be added dynamically, try doing your processing on server side.